# Asynchronous PHP file execution

Tags: php, asynchronous

The current method that I am using will wait for the loop to finish until proceeding with the rest of the code. In my case, it will take forever. Is it possible to run loop.php for every session asynchronously?

Calling the php file:

```
require('loop.php');
```

In loop.php:

```
<?php
while(true) {
    sleep(1);
    //do stuff until session timeout.
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT (MORE DETAILS): So, I want to call a postback URL X seconds after the user has closed the page IF the session meets certain criteria. The thing is that JS can't do that (since it's client based) and .onbeforeunload() doesn't work for my purposes. so I have to create a php file that constantly checks if the user's session exists, but to do that, I need to run it asynchronously for each user.

Comment: You know that's an endless loop right? + every visitor is in his own session, not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the `do stuff until timeout` supposed to be doing? Whatever it is, almost certainly there is a better approach... like pushing those tasks onto a job queue

Comment: This was the most simple example that I could give. The code that I am using is more complicated.

Comment: PHP isn't asynchronous, period. With the right extensions it supports spawning new threads, this may or may not be what you want. You may rather want independent background processes with something like a cron job, or a Gearman/ØMQ/whatever queue/worker setup, or some other inter-process communication tool. There are many options, and without knowing any details we can't really recommend anything.

Comment: You can to perform any io request(http/exec) to that script and don't wait it to answer.

Comment: JS is not only client based. In fact, things like these are easier in JS (serverside).